# Google Apps Script split text till last untill not get blank

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

Our Apps Script needs to check cells `B3:D3`, then `B4:D4`, and so on until reaching a blank cell.

Apps Script code:

```
function work() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataB = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue().toString().split("/");
  var dataC = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue().toString().split("/");
  var dataD = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue().toString().split("/");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dataB.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(dataB[i]);
  }
  
  for (var j = 0; j < dataC.length; j++) {
    sheet.getRange(j + 2, 7).setValue(dataC[j]);
  }
  
  for (var k = 0; k < dataD.length; k++) {
    if (dataD[k]) {
      sheet.getRange(k + 2, 8).setValue(dataD[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a **dummy sheet** for replication. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. If you're unsure, please refer to [Stack Overflow Guide on Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: `and so on until reaching a blank cell.` Would you please explain  this is more detail. Let's say that the is a blank cell in Column D on Row#5. Do you wish to process up to and including row#4 and then stop processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to identify the first row in Columns B or C or D that contains a blank cell. You will use this to limit processing of your existing script.

**Remarks**

- the script defines a variable (`rowcounter`). The final value of the variable is the row number containing a blank cell.

h/t @NightEye [Google App Scripts: How to find first empty cell in row, check value in next column and set values accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258026/1330560)

---

```
function findFirstBlankRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow() - 2;
  var colBRange = sheet.getRange(3, 2, rows, 1);
  var colCRange = sheet.getRange(3, 3, rows, 1);
  var colDRange = sheet.getRange(3, 4, rows, 1);
  // Logger.log(" DEBUG: Range: ColB:"+colBRange.getA1Notation()+", ColC:"+colCRange.getA1Notation()+", ColD:"+colDRange.getA1Notation())

  // 2d array -> 1d array for easier data accessibility
  var colBValues = colBRange.getDisplayValues().flat();
  var colCValues = colCRange.getDisplayValues().flat();
  var colDValues = colDRange.getDisplayValues().flat();

  var rowcounter = 3
  for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+""+",ColB="+colBValues[i]+", ColC:"+colCValues[i]+", ColD:"+colDValues[i])
    // get first blank row
    if(!colBValues[i] || !colCValues[i] || !colDValues[i]  ) {
      //sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1).setValue('X');
      Logger.log("DEBUG: blank row on "+rowcounter)
      //Logger.log("i:"+i+""+",Colb="+colBValues[i]+", ColC:"+colCValues[i]+", ColD:"+colDValues[i])
      break
    }
    else{
      rowcounter++
    }
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE Data**

[image: data]

---

**SAMPLE Results**

[image: results]